# jQuery accordion - what's missing?

Tags: javascript, jquery, accordion

Here's my code;

```
 <head>
        <title>page title</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
  <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#accordion" ).accordion();
  });
  </script>

    <div id="accordion">
      <h3>-shift title-</h3>
      <div><p>-shift content here-</p></div>
      <h3>-shift title-</h3>
      <div><p>-shift content here-</p></div>
    </div>
```

I'm sure i've missed something but my thinking is i've used a CDN and put the function in, the divs are not collapsing?

Comment: jQuery doesn't provide an accordion. You're probably thinking of jQuery UI which you haven't included.

Comment: That's fixed it, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Problem was not including     `<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>`

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using jQuery UI so you'll need to include that library below jQuery

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not totally sure, but I think you may be missing some css files.

Use this as scripts, let's see if it's working:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Comment: And they're missing a JS file